# Corollary of Cauchy Criterion for Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I encountered a corollary of the Cauchy Criterion for convergence that reads:

> A sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $R$ diverges if and only if $\exists$ $\epsilon_0 > 0$ $\exists$ $(n_{k})_{k=1}^{\infty}, (m_{k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ sequences in $N$ such that: $(i)$ $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 ...$ $(ii)$ $m_1 < m_2 < m_3  ...$ $(iii)$ $|x_{m_k}-x_{n_k}| \ge \epsilon_0$ $ \forall$ $ k\in$ $N$

I'm having trouble understanding how this follows from Cauchy's criterion for convergence which states:

> A sequence in $R$ converges if and only if it is a Cauchy Sequence

Comment: Your corollary simply says that a sequence diverges if and only if it is not Cauchy.

Comment: This is not true, we cannot use $\forall \epsilon_0$, take the sequence $0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots$ and $\epsilon_0=47$.

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: @Crostul even if we say that a sequence diverges if and only if it not Cauchy, it does not follow from the fact that a sequence converges if and only if it is Cauchy. Moreover, a divergent sequence can be Cauchy, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: No, a divergent sequence cannot be Cauchy. In fact the following two statements are logically equivalent: $$\text{A sequence converges if and only if it is Cauchy}$$ $$\text{A sequence diverges if and only if it is not Cauchy}$$In particular, the second one can be deduced directly from the first one, contrary to what you said.

Comment: @Shalop of course you mean in a complete space , which is here  $R$.

Comment: I'm only talking about $\mathbb{R}$. That's what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cauchy says:  Convergence $\iff \forall \epsilon > 0 \; \exists N\;  \forall i,j > N \; |x_i - x_j| < \epsilon$

So since "$\sim P \iff \sim Q$" is logically equivalent to "P $\iff$ Q", you get

Divergence $\iff \sim$Convergence $\iff \sim (\forall \epsilon > 0 \; \exists N\;  \forall i,j > N \; |x_i - x_j| < \epsilon)$

$\iff \exists \epsilon > 0 \; \forall N \; \exists i,j > N \; |x_i - x_j| \ge \epsilon$

So now just show that $\forall N \; \exists i,j > N \; |x_i - x_j| \ge \epsilon$ is the same as the existence of increasing sequences as in the original statement.